# Cómo guardar/mover imagen en input file a carpeta del servidor con java?

Tags: java, servlets

Uso servlets 3.0
Tengo el siguiente código

```
 List<Part> fileParts = request.getParts().stream().filter(part -> "files".equals(part.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList()); 

        for (Part filePart : fileParts) {
            String fileName = getSubmittedFileName(filePart);
            InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();


        }
```

Tengo un input file multiple y así los recibo en el servlet, pero ahora cómo hago para guardar el filePart en curso en una carpeta del servidor? por ejemplo en *C:\img*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcionó así:

```
File ruta = new File("C:\\img");


        for (Part filePart : fileParts) {
            String fileName = getSubmittedFileName(filePart);
            InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
            File file = new File(ruta, fileName);
            Files.copy(fileContent, file.toPath());

        }
```